# Is there a downside to sending a refresh token on every request to an API?

Tags: authentication, jwt, access-token

Let's say that my user signs in and the server responds with a refresh token saved in a cookie (SameSite strict, HttpOnly, CSRF token too) and with the access token in response (saved in JS memory).

I read these guidelines in a popular Hasura article. I was wondering, though, with this method, my refresh token would be sent on **every request** since you can't remove a cookie from the client-side.

Is there a downside to this? I feel like sending a token that gives infinite/long-lived access on every request is a bad practice? If so, is there a better approach so that I don't send a refresh token on every request and only on the requests that I want to refresh my access token?

Other ways of doing this would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you imply sending the refresh token on every request is not ideal as it increases the chance of leaking. The simplest way to prevent this is to set the [path attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#path_attribute) of your cookie to the token refresh endpoint. This way your refresh token is only attached to the request when you actually have a need of it.

Keep in mind though that since your refresh token is not attached to other requests it might interfere with middleware on the server that tries to auto-refresh on behalf of the client.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a nonce and a shared secret between the client and server? While not directly answering your question it is somewhat addressing the same challenge. The nonce would make hijacking the cookie futile.

In such a scenario the client and server share a secret. When a request is sent from e.g. the client to the server, a random nonce is generated, and you send {nonce, Hash(nonce, shared-secret)} to the server together with your message.

The server can then verify the authenticity of the client by hashing its shared-secret with the provided nonce.

You need to make sure the same nonce cannot be used twice.